# How to access variables from class to another class

Tags: java

can you help me with my code in java? how can i use the variable input from my main class to another class heres my code.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;
 public class mainSort{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    int num;
    String numString;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    numString=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter how many numbers you  want to Sort");
    num=Integer.parseInt(numString);
  }
}
```

and this is for my another class

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

public class random extends mainSort {

   /*public static void main(String[] args)*/ {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int e;
        int i;
        int g ; ****// here is my problem. how do to use the value of my variable num for my variable g?****
    /*   Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter no.");

        g =input.nextInt();  */


        HashSet<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (i = 0; i < g; i++) {
            e = rand.nextInt(1000);
            randomNumbers.add(e);
            if (randomNumbers.size() <= 0) {
                if (randomNumbers.size() == 0) {
                    g = g;
                }
                g++;
                randomNumbers.add(e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Random numbers are are  : " + randomNumbers);
    }
}
```

i have not yet taken java course but this is our case study for Data Structure. thanks.

Comment: Have you at least covered parameters?  If not, get a book and read up on them.  (And class names should begin with an UpperCase letter.)

Comment: Don't use classes if you don't know about OOP yet, just do all the things in `mainSort` class

Comment: no i haven't covered any topic in java yet but this is our case study in DataStructure. all sorting algorithm which we are requried to write a code in JAVA in OOP approach. can u link me a good tutorial about parameters? i find my JAVA programming book by joyce farrell kinda hard to understand. thanks

Comment: @user2838362, swap: `public static void main(String[] args)` --> `public static void calculate(int num);`, `int g ;` --> `int g = num;` in your second code snippet, and add `random.calculate(num);' after `num=Integer.parseInt(numString);` in your first code snippet. Also you can need to add `package com.user2838362;` in the very beginning of both your files

Answer (score 1):

Try putting`int num` into a public get method then calling it from the other class.

For example:

```
public int getNum() {
return num;
}
```

and then in the class, random, to assign it to g:

```
int g = mainSort.getNum();
```

Comment: i tried adding public int getnum on my main sort class. and the int g=mainsort.getnum on my random class. but error. can i ask what do you call this topic in java? so i could watch tutorials.. thanks

Comment: What's the error that's coming back to you?

Comment: And if you want to look up some tutorials, search for information on instance variables and class variables in created objects.